# IntegrityError: Not Null constraint failed

Tags: django

I have deleted a class from model.py but whenever I run python manage.py migrate, I get this:

> intergrityerror : not null constraint failed: appname_modelclassfieldname.user_id

The most challenging thing is that I had already deleted the model class of the related field django is pointing error at.

Comment: If it's a test database and you don't need any of the data, it might be easiest to delete the migrations, drop the database and start again. If there is important data in the database, then you need to provide a lot more information in your question, including the full traceback, the models and the migration which is failing.

Comment: Are you loading fixtures in your migrations? Because this could also be caused by fixtures that do not apply to your current model constraints. This error happens when you save a model that has a field `user` and you have either not set it or reset it to `None` (or the assigned `user` has not been saved yet).

Comment: It might help to add the relevant stack trace (verbose) of `migrate` and the migration file that the error points to.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a migration before running `migrate`. As you have not specified your Django version, here is what you need to do for the most recent version (1.11) which also works down to at least 1.9:

```
$ ./manage.py makemigrations # > creates a migration file
$ ./manage.py migrate
```

You can specify the the app in the `makemigrations` call if you want.

Concerning:

> The most challenging thing is that i had already deleted the model class of the related field django is pointing error at .

Use a version system for your own health (e.g. GIT) or an editor that supports local versioning (like PyCharm) - best use both - even if you are working alone. (You are never alone, after some weeks, the code looks like it was written by someone else...)

Comment: I did all that that  makemigrations  app_name ,still do not understand why i am getting the error when i am doing migrate.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was an error with the server .I had delete the app and create a new one ,and everything is working just fine now

Comment: You wouldn't need to delete the app entirely, just the migration files under the app in which the instances of your models were created.